# Quick partial differential equation question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

$$ \frac{\partial^2{u(x,y)}}{\partial y^2} -x^2 {u(x,y)}  = 0$$

If i have something like this^. is it okay to use the standard technique for solving second order homogeneous differential equations?

i.e. $ r^2 = x^2 $

Which leads to $${u}(x,y) = A e^{x y} + B e^{-x y}$$

Just wondering because u is in terms of x but the differentials are with respect to y.

Comment: This is not a PDE, since only derivatives in $y$ appear. Here, $x$ can be treated as a parameter, and yes you can treat it as an ODE and use the general solution you wrote.

Comment: Cool, cheers man!

Answer (score 1):

What if

$$u(x,y)=e^{xy}?$$

The first partial wrt $y$ is

$$xe^{xy}$$

and the second one is then

$$x^2e^{xy}=x^2u(x,y).$$